# How to override Back button when a drawer is showing in React 16 / Router V4

Tags: reactjs, router

I have a structure like this, there's a route like:

```
<Route path="/sample-route" component={ComponentA}/>
```

Then `ComponentA` has:

```
<ComponentA>
  <ComponentB/>
  <ComponentC>
    <MaterialUIDrawer/>
  </ComponentC>
</ComponentA>
```

`ComponentC` is used in 5 different routes as a child. The `MaterialUIDrawer` is showing based on a flag in a redux reducer. The problem I'm trying to solve is when the drawer is open, clicking back hides it but also navigates back. I tried solving it like this:

```
window.onpopstate = (e) => {
   if (this.props.isOpen) {
     this.props.toggleDrawer(false);
     this.props.history.replace(this.props.match.url);
   }
 };
```

This has 2 issues:

- If this is the first page you land on, it doesn't actually do anything, the function doesn't trigger
- If you are on a different site and navigate to the url that contains the drawer, hitting Back moves you to a different URL (different domain)

I also tried setting a `<Route/>` in `ComponentC` and then the drawer lives there, but I didn't manage to get it to work, maybe the path is wrong. It felt like this might be the right way though, if path is `/path1`, then drawer lives in `/path1/drawer`, or `/path2/drawer`, etc.

I'm trying to find a way for the Back button in a browser to close the drawer (so execute a function I define) and override the default functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using props here instead of paths, so something like `/path1?drawer=1`, but you will definitely need to use history/location so that the back button can actually go back, so you are on the right trail.

I'm not sure what you are using for a browser history manager, but I would recommend tying off of that instead of leaning on the window pop-state. Your history module should be the source of truth and feed redux, not the other-way around IMO.

Comment: Tried it that way, works. The 'open' function pushes a new route with a url param, The 'close' function replaces the current pathname with the base (without the url param). Then `ComponentC` checks for URL param and sends an `isOpen` prop to the drawer. The flag in the reducer isn't used. Also  I removed the `onpopstate` function, was useless at this point. Ticks all boxes for this use case, thank you.